# What is the maximum number of attribute points and ability points?

Tags: dragon-age-2

Trying to plan my ability trees and stats, including points received from books and any other source I don't know, how many points can be obtained without modding the game?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**150/154*** attribute points and **51/53** talent points:

- 147 attribute points and 49 talent points from leveling to the cap of 50
- 3 attribute points and 2 talent points from *Tomes of Mortal Vessel* and *Tomes of Technique*, respectively

The *Black Emporium* DLC includes the following:

- 4 attribute points and 1 talent point from the same types of tomes mentioned above
- 1 talent point from either the *Elixir of Arcane Technique* or the *Elixir of Physical Technique*. Like the tomes in *Dragon Age: Origins*, these items are class restricted so you can't use both.

I asterisked the number because you can gain additional attribute points and talent points from the following:

Act I:

> Completing the quest *Dark Epiphany* to receive *Avernus's Experimental Draught* nets you 2 attribute points. This quest is only available if you've played *Dragon Age: Origins*, completed the *Warden's Keep* DLC, **and** spared Avernus at the end.

Act II:

> Completing the quest *Night Terrors* can lead to receiving 4 attribute points for solving puzzles and, depending on your dialogue choices, an additional 6 attribute points or 1 talent point.

> Reading any of the evil tomes in the quest *Forbidden Knowledge* nets you 2 attribute points. Once you use this option, it won't appear in any of the other books.

Act III:

Nothing of note.

Comment: Does your first spoiler for Act 2 account for the puzzles, or just the dialogue? I believe the puzzles can net you even more than that.

Comment: @Sapph just the dialogue, but I've added the puzzles as well. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

The "hard" level cap might be 50, but a normal play through won't go anywhere near that.  Expect to finish at level ~22/23.  To be safe, let us assume level 22.  That means 21*3 for 63 attribute points from leveling, and 21 ability points from leveling.  Anything beyond that is gravy.

Mark Trapp correctly lists the availability of bought items to increase stats.  So, add points as appropriate to your game.

However, he neglects a quests which can also reward the player with more attribute and (less commonly) ability points.  I think you get earn 6-8 more attributes, but I only one additional ability point.

Comment: I was going to comment on the absence of that quest line in the previous answer, but wasn't sure how to add spoiler tags to a comment.

Comment: @anthony137 and @Damon: I'm pretty sure I got all three quests that yield possible point gains. If I'm missing something else, I'd love to know what quest you're referring to.

Comment: @Mark The second Act II spoiler is what I was thinking of.